# Is nikah permissible with a foster sister or brother?

Tags: nikah, rada

I have a question regarding nekah (marriage) between a foster sister or brother.

Specifically, my mother breastfed the son of her sister 23 years ago, as I have gone through some of the answers about the same issue I got my answer to some extent based on ayats from Holy Quran and Hadith.

But the part of question remained unanswered, which is my mother has been saying that I took Farhad (the son of her sister) for the purpose to breastfeed but I am not sure, about whether he drank my milk or not, since it was a long time ago.

Can you please state is it permissible to make nekah with this person or not?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. More details are required to answer this question. As to how many times and the quantity she suckled. Her age. Related/duplicate: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9824

Comment: "that I took Farhad" - maybe you wanted to say "that she took Farhad" or " "I took Farhad ... " " ?

Answer (score 1):

As @bleeding Fingers mentioned, totally there are some conditions beside the matter such as how many times ... and so forth.

To breast feed could be proved from two aspects (to be the cause of being Mahram):

1. Informing by some people that the person to be ensured or curtained by their speeches.
2. Certification of two just (fair) men or four just women; but they ought to declare the condition of breasting feed as well. E.g. we have seen that child has drank from the breast of that woman for 24 hours and has not eaten another thing between his/her feeding (beside the other conditions which has stated at the issue #2483 of the reference).

Another significant point is that the child won’t be Mahram to anybody in the case that they doubt if the child has drank enough to be Mahram or not (it is considered as their assumption, not sure); but anyway it is better that the person do precaution in the above-mentioned issue.

---

**For more info, refer to the reference below.**

- [www.aviny.com](http://www.aviny.com/ahkam/ResalehSafiGolpaygani/resale128.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

"my mother breastfed the son of her sister" - no, it is not permissible to marry him, because he is your milk brother.

"that I took Farhad (the son of her sister) for the purpose to breastfeed but I am not sure" - if so, he is your milk son, and even more you cannot marry him.

Comment: I think here you misunderstood something as he's still talking about his mother. And scholars have different opinions about the number of suckelings which make a child a foster child etc. on the other hand his mother doesn't recall whether her sister's son really drunk any drop of her milk! So Farhad is a supposed foster brother to him and the son of his mother's sister!

Answer (score -2):

Even if she drank just once, you cannot marry her as she is your mahram and sister.

Comment: It would be better if you could support your answer with a refference!